# how to get last 10 digit from field using postgresql

Tags: netezza

I am using Netezza database and trying to get only the last 10 digit(string)from a field.

Here is an example of what i have:

```
XMCC123456789
```

what i would like to get is this: C123456789

Comment: Postgres has a function called `right()` which does exactly that. You will need to check the Netezza manual if it supports the same function.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Netezza SQL Extensions Toolkit installed then you can use this:

```
select sql_functions.admin.strright(s.sample,10)
from (select 'XMCC123456789' as sample) s
```

Otherwise the long way is:

```
select substr(s.sample,length(s.sample)-9,10)
from (select 'XMCC123456789' as sample) s
```